# How to merge javascript objects according to key?

Tags: javascript, object, merge, associative-array

I have one array of object as below :

```
[ { user: 'Abc', badge: [ 6 ] },
  { user: 'PQR', badge: [ 7 ] },
  { user: 'PQR', badge: [ 1 ] },
  { user: 'PQR', badge: [ 2 ] },
  { user: 'XYZ', badge: [ -5 ] } ]
```

I have created this object with the following javascript code :

```
        for (var j = 0; j < aR.length; j++) 
    {
        if (typeof aR[j] != 'undefined' && aR[j] != null)
       {

                    recievedUser =aR[j].get("receiver").id;
                    badge = aR[j].get("rBTypes");

                    if(recievedUser!= undefined && badge != undefined )
                    result.push({'user': recievedUser, 'badge': badge});
       }
    }
```

Now I want to merge this array like :

```
[     { user: 'Abc', badge: [ 6 ] },
      { user: 'PQR', badge: [ 7 ,1,2] },
      { user: 'XYZ', badge: [ -5 ] } ]
```

How I can do this ?

I also want to find the user with most badges ?

Comment: Tip: it becomes trivial when you restructure your result to `{ Abc: [6], PQR: [7,1,2], ... }`

Comment: Even that is ok for me!

Comment: `{ user: 'PQR', badge: [ 7 ],[1],[2] }` is not a valid object literal

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with `thisArgs` for a temporary object as reference to the grouped elements.

```js
var data = [{ user: 'Abc', badge: [6] }, { user: 'PQR', badge: [7] }, { user: 'PQR', badge: [1] }, { user: 'PQR', badge: [2] }, { user: 'XYZ', badge: [-5] }],
    grouped = [],
    mostUser = [];

data.forEach(function (a, i) {
    if (!this[a.user]) {
        this[a.user] = { user: a.user, badge: [] };
        grouped.push(this[a.user]);
    }
    this[a.user].badge = this[a.user].badge.concat(a.badge);
    if (!i || this[a.user].badge.length > this[mostUser[0]].badge.length) {
        mostUser = [a.user];
        return;
    }
    if (a.user !== mostUser[0] && this[a.user].badge.length === this[mostUser[0]].badge.length) {
        mostUser.push(a.user);
    }
}, Object.create(null));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(mostUser, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you want to accomplish the trivial restructured results which deceze mentioned in the comments of your question.  Simple change the push statement in your code to:  `result.push({recievedUser: badge});`

Now for calculating which user has the most badges:

```
// Add these variables here
var most_badges = 0;
var user_with_most;

for (var j = 0; j < attendeeReflections.length; j++) 
{
    if (typeof attendeeReflections[j] != 'undefined' && attendeeReflections[j] != null)
     {
         recievedUser =attendeeReflections[j].get("receiver").id;
         badge = attendeeReflections[j].get("requestedBehaviorTypes");

         // Add this check here
         if(badge.length > most_badges) {
            most_badges = badge.length;
            user_with_most = recievedUser;
         }
         // Now you have your results

         if(recievedUser!= undefined && badge != undefined )
             result.push({'user': recievedUser, 'badge': badge});
     }
}
```

Now you have the user with the most badges stored in the `user_with_most` variable and the amount of badges that user has stored in the `most_badges` variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can either modify your function checking the returning result before pushing in a new item,

or with the output you already have you can use Array.reduce to organize your array,

here's a solution with reduce():

```js
var a = [ { user: 'Abc', badge: [ 6 ] },
  { user: 'PQR', badge: [ 7 ] },
  { user: 'PQR', badge: [ 1 ] },
  { user: 'PQR', badge: [ 2 ] },
  { user: 'XYZ', badge: [ -5 ] } ]


var r= a.reduce((ac,x) => {
   (ac.some(z => {
     if(z.user === x.user)
       z.badge.push(x.badge[0]);
      return (z.user === x.user);}))
   || (ac.push(x));
    return ac;
    
  },[])
console.log(r)
```